# html5 positioning - aside, figure, section,

Tags: css, html

I am having an issue with placement on my index page.

I have a simple CSS slideshow inside an `<aside>` tag that is made of figure tags. I am trying to place it next to my body `<section>` but something is pushing my section down and leaving an odd white space.

I am aware I can have these lined easily with float however that affects my page resizing and that is an issue I can't have.

[image: error]

```css
/*
  created: 6/4/16;
last modified: 6/4/16;
description: index.html, jobs.html, apply.html, 
  enhancements.html, about.html;
*/

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: georgia, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}
body {
  font-family: georgia, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("/styles/images/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 50px 70px 50px 70px;
}
nav {
  font-family: georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b2babb;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #b2babb;
  padding: 10px 3px 20px 3px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}
aside {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
}
section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 370px;
  margin-left: 340px;
  /*border: 1px solid #b2babb;
 padding: 30px 3px 3px 3px;*/
  background-color: white;
}
section img {
  float: right;
}
footer {
  clear: both;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*removes underline*/

a:visited {
  color: #666699;
}
img {
  /*rounds edges of images inside body and floats right*/
  border-radius: 8px;
  float: right;
}
/*Required Enhancements to about page*/

#name {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
}
#studentnum {
  font-family: courier, monospace;
}
#me {
  float: right;
  border-style: double;
  padding: 40px;
}
div.img {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
}
div.about {
  width: 925px;
  height: 375px;
}
#tutorname {
  text-align: left;
}
#tutorial {
  text-align: right;
}
#course {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}
table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}
table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table td {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}
#email {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: small;
}
/*End of enhancements to about page*/

/*Slideshow on index.html*/

/* http://themarklee.com/2013/10/16/simple-crossfading-slideshow-css/ */

.css-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 1em auto .5em auto;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
  max-width: 530px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(6),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(7) {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside class="css-slideshow">
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/office.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Our Oiffices</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/officework.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Working with us</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/sampleweb.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Website example #1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="images/sampleweb2.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Website example #2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/building.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Our building</figcaption>
  </figure>
</aside>
<section>
  <h2>Think IT Foward</h2> 
  <p>We are a new company which aims to advance our current way of life with new technologies.
    <br>We use the latest software to create dynamic webpages that re-invent what is currently on the market.
    <br>Our servers go above and beyond in delivering reliability and speed, ensuring the user is left with a brand new web-browsing experience.
    <p>
      <img src="/images/Untitled.png">
      <br>Craving a new web experience for your customers? Enquire now.
      <a href="jobs.html">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <em>We're hiring</em>
      </a>
</section>
```

Comment: your width of second box is 70%, please reduce it till it fit in one line. Because it is calculating 70% + margin ... Always use universal selector to apply `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: thank you for your reply! that still didnt fix the issue :(
i have uploaded a screenshot showing the issue even after i've changed the width.
where do i need to use the universal selector?

Comment: Where is the whitespace? Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Add this line at the beginning of your CSS: * {box-sizing: border-box;}

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFc9.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the top margin on the aside and float it, and remove inline-block from the section, they should play well together.

The page resizing issue with float is easily dealt with. It's better to wrap these contents in a container and ceter it on the screen, rather than have these elements trying to find their own positions randomly.

```css
/*
  created: 6/4/16;
last modified: 6/4/16;
description: index.html, jobs.html, apply.html, 
  enhancements.html, about.html;
*/

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: georgia, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}
body {
  font-family: georgia, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("/styles/images/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 50px 70px 50px 70px;
}
nav {
  font-family: georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b2babb;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #b2babb;
  padding: 10px 3px 20px 3px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}
aside {
  float:left;
}
section {
  width: 70%;
  height: 370px;
  margin-left: 340px;
  /*border: 1px solid #b2babb;
 padding: 30px 3px 3px 3px;*/
  background-color: white;
}
section img {
  float: right;
}
footer {
  clear: both;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*removes underline*/

a:visited {
  color: #666699;
}
img {
  /*rounds edges of images inside body and floats right*/
  border-radius: 8px;
  float: right;
}
/*Required Enhancements to about page*/

#name {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
}
#studentnum {
  font-family: courier, monospace;
}
#me {
  float: right;
  border-style: double;
  padding: 40px;
}
div.img {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
}
div.about {
  width: 925px;
  height: 375px;
}
#tutorname {
  text-align: left;
}
#tutorial {
  text-align: right;
}
#course {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}
table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}
table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table td {
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}
#email {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: small;
}
/*End of enhancements to about page*/

/*Slideshow on index.html*/

/* http://themarklee.com/2013/10/16/simple-crossfading-slideshow-css/ */

.css-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto .5em auto;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.css-slideshow figure {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 495px;
  height: 370px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #666;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.css-slideshow-attr {
  max-width: 530px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-style: italic;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a {
  color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(6),
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(7) {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 24s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 18s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 12s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 6s infinite;
}
.css-slideshow figure:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  -moz-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  -ms-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  -o-animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade 30s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes "xfade" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  14.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.67% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside class="css-slideshow">
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/office.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Our Oiffices</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/officework.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Working with us</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/sampleweb.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Website example #1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="images/sampleweb2.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Website example #2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="/images/building.jpg" width="336" height="370" />
    <figcaption>Our building</figcaption>
  </figure>
</aside>
<section>
  <h2>Think IT Foward</h2> 
  <p>We are a new company which aims to advance our current way of life with new technologies.
    <br>We use the latest software to create dynamic webpages that re-invent what is currently on the market.
    <br>Our servers go above and beyond in delivering reliability and speed, ensuring the user is left with a brand new web-browsing experience.
    <p>
      <img src="/images/Untitled.png">
      <br>Craving a new web experience for your customers? Enquire now.
      <a href="jobs.html">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <em>We're hiring</em>
      </a>
</section>
```